# Textfiles for Information Retrieval

Tags: information-retrieval, documents

I am searching for sample .txt files for information Retrieval.
Would be nice if there are sets of documents(around 20 documents) regarding one topic, e.g., sports, music, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many datasets available, for instance:

Datasets used to evaluate IR systems:
http://www.daviddlewis.com/resources/testcollections/

More IR datasets:
http://boston.lti.cs.cmu.edu/callan/Data/

A comprehensive list of several datasets:
http://zitnik.si/mediawiki/index.php?title=Datasets

The classic news groups dataset: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html

Much bigger, news articles: http://research.signalmedia.co/newsir16/signal-dataset.html